# How can I fix TTF fonts' ligatures (tt, ti, fi, ff, etc) in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, fonts

With certain Windows fonts there is a display issue where ligature-kerning seems to flip out and make the two letters bold. Here's a screenshot of an email using Helvetica in Firefox:

[image]

As you can see, it seems to be something about the way crossed characters (`t` and `f`) connect to each other and letters like `i`.

I've had this problem for a very long time (over multiple systems) and wondered if anybody has ever seen similar issues popping up and found a way to fix them.

Note: I think this does just affect Firefox. Chrome and LibreOffice are both fine.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Another solution that will work with all applications, including Libre Office, is given by [aldeby](http://web.archive.org/web/20120111115535/http://linux.aldeby.org/post/m-fonts-eg-calibri-display-ugly-in-linux.html):

Edit or create the file `~/.fonts.conf` and paste this code in it:

```
<match target="font" >
<edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
<bool>false</bool>
</edit>
</match>
```

Make sure to keep the XML structure.

Log out and in again, and Calibri (and possibly some other fonts) will look much better (actually even better than with the other answers given here, because the ugly bitmap substitutions are completely disabled).

Comment: This one's a better solution than the earlier ones, as it's a global fix, and eliminating ligatures is a bodge. Ligatures are there to make text more pleasing to read, and to turn them off to work around a configuration problem is not ideal.

Comment: Anyone who is slightly OCD or anal retentive enough to care about properly formatting the contents of this XML file (of course you Linux folks would _never_ care about such things ;-) ): `<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd"><fontconfig><match target="font"><edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign"><bool>false</bool></edit></match></fontconfig>`

Comment: Link to aldeby now leads to some phishing scam site

Comment: @charsi thanks, I replaced it with a link to the Web Archive.

Comment: I didn't even have to logout and login again. Simply refreshing the page (in Firefox) and restarting the application (LibreOffice) was enough.

Answer (score 11):

Disabling [ligatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature) (see [Calimo's `fonts.conf` answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/186940/260416)) **is the wrong direction!** It may remove those over-aliased "bold" ligatures in fonts like [Calibri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri), but it also removes some of the beauty of typography.  That's rather similar to shrinking the font until you can't tell the difference.

I solved this for my system by removing the Calibri font, installing [Carlito](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280557), which is "[*metric-compatible*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric-compatible) with Calibri" and is packaged with "a mapping entry to fontconfig (local.conf)," and refreshing my font cache:

```
$ rm ~/.fonts/microsoft/CALIBRI*
$ sudo apt install fonts-crosextra-carlito
$ fc-cache
```

You can then verify that Carlito stands in for Calibri:

```
$ fc-match Calibri
Carlito-Regular.ttf: "Carlito" "Regular"
```

(If this doesn't work, you may need something like `sudo rm /usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/calibri*` though the case and exact location may differ.)

Before removing Microsoft's Calibri, I saved a test document in LibreOffice that used Calibri and took a screen shot.  After doing that, I quit LibreOffice, opened it again, and then loaded my test document.  The "Calibri" font name was italicized to indicate that it was substituted for.  I took a screen shot of this substituted version and pasted it below the original:

[image: Calibri tests]

The above text is a pair of screen shots of 13pt Calibri, with Microsoft's Calibri above Carlito as matched by fontconfig.  There is no bold, no formatting, "pair kerning" enabled, as rendered by LibreOffice 5.0.5.1.

Carlito is quite close to Calibri, ligatures render properly, and it's much prettier overall.

You can do the same with [Caladea](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168879) for [Cambria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambria_%28typeface%29) with `fonts-crosextra-caladea` and you can use Google's [Croscore fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croscore_fonts) Arimo, Tinos, and Cousine for [Arial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial), [Times New Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman), and [Courier New](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_New) with `fonts-croscore`.  Learn more at Debian's [Substituting Calibri and Cambria Fonts](https://wiki.debian.org/SubstitutingCalibriAndCambriaFonts) wiki.

### But what about Helvetica?

This question asks about the [**Helvetica**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helvetica) font, which is Apple's preferred [sans-serif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sans-serif) font.  Microsoft preferred [Arial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial) before it changed to Calibri.  The default Linux mapping varies by distribution, but it's typically either [Nimbus Sans L](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimbus_Sans#Nimbus_Sans_L) or else [Liberation Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liberation_fonts), e.g.

```
$ fc-match Helvetica
n019003l.pfb: "Nimbus Sans L" "Regular"
```

If you run that and get Arial, that's a pretty good reason for having the ligature issue described above – Arial is not a great font.

Helvetica has quite the culture surrounding it and I can't find a font that is fully metric-compatible with Helvetica.  Arial (and fonts metrically compatible with Arial, including Liberation Sans and its fork, [Arimo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croscore_fonts), have identical character widths (which mean they're "mostly" metric compatible; text will wrap the same way as with Helvetica). Among the free fonts, Liberation Sans and Nimbus Sans [seem](http://www.grputland.com/2013/11/multiplatform-helvetica-like-font-stack.html) to have the most similar aesthetics.

There's also [IBM Plex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Plex), a new font with big money behind it<sup>[[1](https://qz.com/1124664/ibm-plex-with-its-first-ever-custom-corporate-font-ibm-is-freeing-itself-from-the-tyranny-of-helvetica/)][[2](https://www.fastcodesign.com/90150350/ibms-quest-to-design-the-helvetica-of-the-21st-century)]</sup>. Plex is designed to replace Helvetica (it also has condensed sans as well as serif and monospace fonts) in all of IBM's materials, though it is not at all metric-compatible to Helvetica or other fonts.  Font Squirrel has a nice view of [samples of the Plex fonts](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/ibm-plex).

### Fontconfig aliases

To manually alias Helvetica to another font (and therefore not need to remove Calibri and/or Arial, though in that case you should also manually alias those), edit your `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` file (for older systems, that's `~/.fonts.conf`. To avoid confusion, I symlink the latter to the former) as noted in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/885130/260416), adding a new `<alias>` section for Helvetica (this one uses Arimo. Make sure you have it installed):

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>

  <alias>
    <family>Helvetica</family>
    <prefer><family>Arimo</family></prefer>
  </alias>

</fontconfig>
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than the accepted one. I want to point out there is a convenient conf file available on the arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Croscore_Fonts

Comment: first line should now be sudo rm -R /usr/share/fonts/truetype/calibri

Comment: If one's fc-match Helvetica result IS arial on linux, do you know how to force Liberation Sans? Just delete Arial? Thanks

Comment: @dez93_2000 – that's probably `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/msttcorefonts/callibri*`. I'll update my answer to address font aliasing since it won't fit in a comment.

Comment: I carefully inspected the rendered results of the accepted answer (using the font Calibri), and found no difference at all compared to a known good renderer. There was absolutely no beauty missing.

Comment: @Marc.2377 – Beauty is in the eye of the beholder. If my first paragraph didn't convince you, make sure you're using a ligature-supporting font like Carlito or Arimo and then type `lflffii` and zoom in on it in each scenario. Pay attention to the tops and crosses in each f. See also my first link's [Latin alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature#Latin_alphabet) section or the demonstration of the `fi` ligature in its [MS Word demo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthographic_ligature#/media/File:Word_default_no_ligatures.tiff)

Comment: I *do* have the ligatures, after disabling the bitmap fonts following Calimo's answer (a procedure that is also describer [in the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_configuration#Disable_bitmap_fonts). I find the first paragraph of your answer misleading since it indicates that disabling bitmap is equivalent to disabling the ligatures, and as I verified that is not true.

Comment: Ooh, I just realized Calimo has *two* answers on this page. One of them indeed suggests disabling ligatures. I apologize.

Comment: @AdamKatz I consinder ligatures not as a beauty more as a atrocity, it reduces reability, see e.g. https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Ligature_drawing.svg . PS The accepted answer disables bitmaps not and does not direclty disable ligatures.

Comment: @JoKalliauer – The beauty of ligatures is of course opinion-driven, but it's designed for legibility; see my last comment above. As to the bitmaps, it is my understanding that they're used in place of ligatures in that given font, thus my advice to use a better font.

Answer (score 7):

[lgarzo's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/125308/22949) will work *only* on websites that have a "noligs" class on the text (most websites don't).

To globally disable ligatures on all websites, add the following line to your `userChrome.css`:

```
* { -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0; }
```

The easiest way to do that is to create a new style with the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/stylish/) extension.

Comment: +1 for the Stylish suggestion. AFAIR I've quoted Mozilla documentation (since I had expected the OP to be able to transform that as he wished :)) My intention was to include the rule into the page's CSS. (Cannot check the source, though. It seems to be down ATM.)

Comment: That syntax was only valid until Firefox 14, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161336/4464570, and is now no longer recognized by the browser. I edited your post to update it with the current syntax.

Answer (score 4):

A few remarks popped into my mind while looking at the image:

- The ligatures seem to be *anti-aliased*, while the rest of the text is not. Therefore it looks fatter than normal text (although I cannot deny it also looks bold).
- AFAIK the Helvetica font is a *non-standard font*, i.e. does not come with default Windows installations. Do you have it installed, or is it a different font?

I think the problem is based on the font not supporting ligatures/kerning correctly.

You can disable ligatures in FF with the CSS rule below:

```
/* disable common ligatures, usually on by default */
.noligs { -moz-font-feature-settings: "liga" 0; }
```

Source: [CSS Reference:Mozilla Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-font-feature-settings)

Comment: That syntax was only valid until Firefox 14, according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15161336/4464570, and is now no longer recognized by the browser. I edited your post to update it with the current syntax.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Calimo's answer, Archlinux users can find help https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration - Disable bitmap fonts

It was suggested to created a local config file in `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/20-no-embedded.conf`, but I went for a system wide option by putting the config in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/20-no-embedded.conf`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
      <bool>false</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Then just restart the app (in my case thunderbird).

Comment: If right below the "<match target="font">" line you add:

     <test name="family">
      <string>Calibri</string>
    </test>

Or whatever the font name is (Helvetica), you will only edit the font settings for that specific font.

Comment: The permission should be 644, not 777, because you are putting a file (not a symlink) there.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by https://askubuntu.com/a/186940/676490 with a valid xml-structure:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
 <match target="font" >
  <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
   <bool>false</bool>
  </edit>
  <edit name="fontfeatures" mode="append">
   <string>calt off</string>
   <string>clig off</string>
   <string>dlig off</string>
   <string>liga off</string>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <alias>
  <family>Helvetica</family>
  <prefer><family>Arimo</family></prefer>
 </alias>
 <alias>
  <family>Calibri</family>
  <prefer><family>Carlito</family></prefer>
 </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

and save this file under `~/.fonts.conf`