# Problems with ttf font rendering under LibreOffice

Tags: fonts, microsoft, libreoffice

Microsoft TTF-fonts such as Calibri and Cambria aren't rendered correctly at certain page zoom levels:

[image: Comparison between the system font and Cambria at different zoom levels]

I installed the Microsoft fonts manually by placing them in the `~/.fonts` directory and updating the font cache.

Is there any way to improve Microsoft font rendering under LibreOffice?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Fonts like Calibri and Cambria resort to using embedded bitmaps when adjusted to small sizes.

To disable this font behaviour, put the following into `$HOME/.fonts.conf`:

```
<match target="font" >
     <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
         <bool>false</bool>
     </edit>
</match>
```

Create the file if it doesn't exist.

**Restart to take effect.**

*Sources

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=724818 (registration required)

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/fonts-conf.5.html*

*NOTE:*
`$HOME/.fonts.conf` is deprecated in Ubuntu 12.10
Instead, paste the above XML code (as root) in /etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf

Comment: This worked great, thank you! Makes we wonder why this isn't the default behaviour. Are there any downsides to disabling the embedded bitmaps?

Comment: @Glutanimate As far as I'm aware, very few fonts use this technology. So you should never run into any problems. I agree, this should be default in the global fonts.conf

Comment: For 14.04, ~/.config/font-manager/local.conf is a better location to add that (assuming you don't want to mangle the system-wide setting.)

Comment: This worked better for me: http://askubuntu.com/a/594983/15943

Comment: You do *not* need to restart, just run `fc-cache -f` and re-open whatever application was rendering the font

Answer (score 9):

Instead of putting the XML code in `/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf` (which actually just includes files from `$HOME/.config/fontconfig/conf.d` or `$HOME/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`) put the XML code in a file under the two mentioned directories in your `$HOME/.config/fontconfig/` directory. Don't mess with the system configuration files as this will make system upgrades more complicated.

Answer (score 7):

I solved this for my system by removing the [Calibri](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calibri) font, installing [Carlito](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=280557), which is "metric-compatible with Calibri" and is packaged with "a mapping entry to fontconfig (local.conf)," refreshing my font cache, and restarting LibreOffice:

```
$ rm ~/.fonts/microsoft/CALIBRI*
$ sudo apt install fonts-crosextra-carlito
$ fc-cache
```

Here's a before and after with Microsoft at the top and Carlito below:

[image: Calibri tests]

You can do the same with [Caladea](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=168879) for [Cambria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cambria_%28typeface%29) with `fonts-crosextra-caladea` and you can use [Croscore fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Croscore_fonts) Arimo, Tinos, and Cousine for [Arial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arial), [Times New Roman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman), and [Courier New](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Courier_New) with `fonts-croscore`.

See [my full post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125297/how-can-i-fix-ttf-fonts-ligatures-tt-ti-fi-ff-etc-in-firefox/730273#730273) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue on Ubuntu LTS 18.04, and then again after upgrading to 20.04 LTS. Calibri looked horrible on LibreOffice and Firefox. The above method worked for me as follows:

Create the file described above and save as fonts.conf in $HOME/.config/fontconfig

Then rebuild the font cache: sudo fc-cache -fv

I'm not sure if the last step was necessary, but I did it anyway before checking the font rendering.

Calibri now looks perfect on LibreOffice and in Firefox.