# How to activate LibreOffice anti-aliasing?

Tags: graphics, libreoffice, antialiasing

LibreOffice looks terrible compared to the rest of my OS and other text applications, such as MS Word. It looks like it has no anti-aliasing, how can I activate it?

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 if that helps.

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version?

Comment: 14.04, I'll add it to the text for reference

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the reason for bad looking fonts is disabled anti-aliasing, then there are few things you could try:

1. In LibreOffice: Go to *Tools* in the top menu -> then *Options*. In the left treeview go to *LibreOffice* -> *View* (4th from top). Here are some settings for LibreOffice (like "use Anti-Aliasing").
2. If your whole system lacks of Anti-Aliasing (what I don't think according to your question) you can install the *Tweak-Tool*. Open it, go to *fonts* and choose your way of Anti-Aliasing and font-optimization.

Just give it a try!

If you are using ttf fonts instead and nothing helps see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181135/problems-with-ttf-font-rendering-under-libreoffice) for further help.

Comment: I've done both of those things and it still looks bad. Also, note that the menu was under `Tools` not `Extras`.

Comment: I will try the last resort and see how that goes.

Comment: [The last answer worked](http://askubuntu.com/a/486143/395029) after restarting my PC.