# How to get Calibri font to display nicely

Tags: 14.04, fonts, antialiasing

I have Calibri installed because it's the default font for M$ Office and so many of my clients send me documents using this font.

But it displays without anti-aliasing which is horrible. It's like being on a Windoze machine again :-O

[image: screenshot]

It only seems to happen at small sizes; it's antialiased at larger sizes. Can I disable this?

EDIT:

My `/etc/fonts/config.avail/10-antialias.conf` contains

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
<!--  Use the Antialiasing -->
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

And

```
% fc-match calibri          
calibri.ttf: "Calibri" "Regular"
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### MS-C fonts embedded bitmaps

Per comments to this answer, the most common problem with MS C-fonts (Cambria, Calibri...) is that they use embedded bitmaps. To change this disable them. Either in

1. `~/.fonts.conf`
2. or `~/.config/font-manager/local.conf` in 14.04; Font Manager reserves the right to manage the `~/.fonts.conf` file, thanks @Alain)
3. or `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` (per @SpinUp and @Glutamine's comments)
   you need to add this XML snippet:

```
<!-- disable embedded bitmaps in fonts to fix Calibri, Cambria, etc. -->
<match target="font">
   <edit mode="assign" name="embeddedbitmap"><bool>false</bool></edit>
</match>
```

### Antialiasing toggle

You should be able if you toggle configs in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/`, namely antialiasing, less so autohinting. How to do so: change the `true` to `false` in `10-antialias.conf` or vice versa and you toggled the antialiasing and can see if it helps. Similarly for `10-autohinting.conf`. This toggles the setting for all fonts AFAIR, so just take a look if it helps your case, you'll know if the problem is there or not.

Note: read-only file needs `sudo` to be modified (or needs to be made write-also prior to writing to it), so whatever your editor is (mine is `vim`), run it with `sudo`: `sudo vim /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-antialias.conf`.

[image: animated gif showing which true to change to false]

### Cache rebuilding and font-stack changes

Also, oft-advised solution with fonts is rebuilding cache: `sudo fc-cache -v -f`. Especially if you made changes to font stack (installed new fonts, deleted, moved etc.).

Also, what does `fc-match calibri` display? Why I ask: in my case to display Calibri well, I had to fall back to DejaVu Sans, otherwise I had a missing ligatures problem: see [my Calibri question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251821/blank-missing-ligatures-tt-ti-fi-ff-etc-in-ff-when-cambria-calibri-fon). I did that by deleting the Calibri regular font file (`.ttf`). So, for me, fc-match output is as follows:

```
➜  ~  fc-match calibri
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```