# What is the font in Ubuntu which is just called "Sans"?

Tags: fonts

There are lots of sans fonts in Ubuntu, for example "Liberation Sans", "FreeSans", "Deja Vu Sans", "Noto Sans". But who made the one that is just called "Sans" and which package is it from?

[image: screenshot of the sans font]

Comment: I see also "Serif" in your screenshot... Which tool are you using?

Comment: Maybe `fc-match sans` is what you need? That command gives me `DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Font names in Ubuntu are managed by library named [`fontconfig`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/fontconfig/). `fontconfig` has a notion of *aliases*; four of those aliases are `sans`, `sans-serif`, `serif`, and `monospace`. To see what actual fonts are pointed to by those aliases use the command [`fc-match`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/fc-match.1.html):

```
$ fc-match sans-serif
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
$ fc-match sans
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
$ fc-match serif
DejaVuSerif.ttf: "DejaVu Serif" "Book"
$ fc-match monospace
DejaVuSansMono.ttf: "DejaVu Sans Mono" "Book"
```

To modify the meaning of the standard aliases `sans`, `sans-serif`, `serif` and `monospace` you must create or edit a per-user configuration file, `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` (or `~/.fonts.conf`, depending on `fontconfig` version and system configuration). (You can of course edit the system-wide configuration file, but that would be rude.) For example,

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <alias>
    <family>serif</family>
    <prefer><family>Liberation Serif</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans-serif</family>
    <prefer><family>Liberation Sans</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>sans</family>
    <prefer><family>Liberation Sans</family></prefer>
  </alias>
  <alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer><family>Liberation Mono</family></prefer>
  </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

See a worked out example at [How to Set Default Fonts on Linux](https://seasonofcode.com/posts/how-to-set-default-fonts-and-font-aliases-on-linux.html) on [Season of Code](https://seasonofcode.com/).