# Lato Font Not Displayed Correctly Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, fonts

I'm using Lato font on Ubuntu 16.04.
Why is the gap of character "f" and "i" or "t" and "i" too narrow ? On the web, it is displayed as expected.
[image: Lato font on Web vs System]

Any suggestion?

Comment: I have tried the Lato font preview on two sites, and the results are never the same as yours (this site : http://www.latofonts.com/lato-free-fonts/ gives the same preview as your ubuntu preview, and this site:https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Lato gives a third result).

Comment: If google also display it weirdly then i'll just search alternative font.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to raise the precedence. Create the file `~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-lato.conf` and give it this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <alias>
                <family>sans-serif</family>
                <prefer>
                        <family>Lato</family>
                </prefer>
        </alias>
</fontconfig>
```

Comment: I think the OP has a problem with ligatures, either because both preview are using different font version or a different setting, but the font looks like the same.

Comment: @pim: Maybe. The above is a long shot, but can't hurt...

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I've tried your solution, it doesn't work. I've try to disable ligature described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125297/how-can-i-fix-ttf-fonts-ligatures-tt-ti-fi-ff-etc-in-firefox/186940) and it doesn't work either. My last option might be metric compatible font.